# How to make bot search whole message for specific strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
if ("coffee") in message.content:
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "I am a Teapot")
```

I want the bot to be able to pick up the string 'coffee' in any message.
ex: [User]: I want to get coffee.  [Bot]: I am a Teapot

Comment: Do you want it to detect the substring `"coffee"` in words like `"coffeepot"`?  What about the word `"Coffee"`?

Comment: well, substring detection would be great, but right now, i would like to get the bot to detect the string `"coffee"` as the whole string within the messages received. And the capital strings arent too important, couldn't i use listing to get `"Coffee"` or `"COFFEE"` ? @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the `on_message` event like so

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if "coffee" in message.content:
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "I am a Teapot")
```

Comment: sorry, i should have posted that part. this is what i have as of right now.
`import discord


client = discord.Client()


@client.event  
async def on_message(message):  
    if message.author == client.user:  
        return


    if ("coffee") in message.content:  
       await bot.send_message(message.channel, "I am a Teapot")  
  
@client.event  
async def on_ready():  
    print('Logged in as')  
    print(client.user.name)  
    print(client.user.id)  
    print('------')  
  
client.run('token')`

Comment: @D.Jon What about the code you posted isn't working?

Comment: i'm not too sure, this is the message I get when I try to trigger the event.
`Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jon\errorbot.py", line 20, in on_message
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "I am a Teapot")
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined`

which is weird, since the bot.py file is not located in users folder. and im not sure about the client.py

Comment: @D.Jon You named your `Client` `client`, not `bot`.

Comment: which ones do i need to change to `bot`?

Comment: change `bot.send_message` to `client.send_message`.